# Is it necessary to be admin to get contacts? - Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

If my o365 account doesn't a global admin, just a user, I can't grant permissions in Azure AD? Because if I don't grant the appropriate privileges in Azure AD, I can't get contacts, for example like this: graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/contacts

(No sign-in user, just acquired access token and use http requests)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not necessary.

The none admin user can grant the permissions not require admin privilege. To list contacts, you only need `Contacts.Read` permission which the normal user can grant also.

More detail about this REST and permission, you can refer links below:

[List contacts](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_contacts)

[Microsoft Graph permissions reference](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference)

Comment: I know that, but I use Azure AD Graph API, and it says "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: I suggest that you checking the `roles` or `scp` claim by decoding the token from [this site](https://jwt.io/) to see whether the permission is in this token. If yes, please acquire the token and test again to make sure this issue is not caused by cache of server.

Comment: @Magg Is the issue fixed.

Comment: Now it's working. There was a problem with the roles. Thank you!